# Cartão de crédito no app android

Tags: android, sqlite

Pessoal é melhor a pessoa salvar o numero, data de vencimento e cvv do cartão, no proprio app (sqlite) ou no banco de dados na web?

Answer (score 1):

Existem vantagens e desvantagens em cada abordagem:

**1- Salvar no APP:**

**Vantagens:** Não é necessário redigitar informações pois elas ficam salvas diretamente no celular; Funcionamento parcialmente offline.

**Desvantagens:** Mudar de aparelho significa redigitar os dados; Insegurança pois os dados ficam acessíveis a qualquer pessoa que utilize o celular; Consumo de memória do celular para o armazenamento dos dados

**2- Salvar na WEB:**

**Vantagens:** Não é necessário redigitar informações pois elas ficam salvas num servidor remoto; Não utiliza memória interna do celular para armazenar os dados; Segurança devido ao armazenamento das informações num sistema remoto associado ao usuário e não ao celular; É possível utilizar a aplicação em qualquer aparelho celular.

**Desvantagens:** Aplicação só funciona com acesso à Internet; Necessidade de cadastro das informações num registro do servidor; Latência ao carregar informações de um servidor remoto; Necessidade de autenticação para ter acesso às informações do servidor remoto.

Você precisa ponderar quais desvantagens podem ser arcadas dependendo do propósito da aplicação. Eu costumo optar pelo salvamento na WEB já que hoje em dia praticamente toda aplicação requer acesso à internet.

Comment: obrigado Giuliana =)

Answer (score 1):

**Resposta**

1. Por uma questão de segurança e que pode ser contratual ou de termos de privacidade, é melhor que essas informações sobre o cartão fiquem no banco de dados do servidor. Nada impede que o celular seja furtado e que os dados fiquem na mão de pessoas mal intencionadas porque conseguiram acesso ao banco de dados SQLite do aplicativo.
2. Caso o usuário delete o aplicativo de seu celular e baixe novamente o mesmo futuramente será necessário informar de novo os dados do cartão de crédito.

**Conclusão**

É melhor salvar as informações em um banco de dados na web assumindo e garantindo compromissos de Segurança da Informação com o cliente. E não há porque salvar os dados do cartão de crédito no SQLite porque para fazer uma transação ou qualquer outra consulta utilizando o cartão de crédito é necessário acesso a Internet.

Comment: obrigado Giancarlo =)